# Can't acces my Portable Area in MVCContrib MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib, portable-areas

I need help. I can't access my portable area from my main project. I build everything and I get a 404 error when trying to access this portable area (localhost:123/IW/Home), but all my regular areas are working fine (ex: localhost:123/Portal/Home)

Here's what I did in order to install my portable area
-I downloaded MVCContrib
-I added reference to MVCContrib.dll in my main project (called WAB)

-I created a new Class Librairy project in the same solution as WAB.
-This new Class Librairy is called IWPortableArea and I added the necessary assemblies references (MVCContrib, System.mvc, ...)

-I created a IWRegistration:

```
namespace IWPortableArea
{
    public class IWRegistration : PortableAreaRegistration
    {
        public override void RegisterArea(System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext context, IApplicationBus bus)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "iw",
                "iw/{controller}.aspx/{action}",
                new { controller = "login", action = "index" });

            RegisterAllAreas(GetType());
        }

        public override string AreaName
        {
            get { return "iw"; }
        }


    }
}
```

-I created a simple controller that's not making use of any view file:

```
namespace IWPortableArea.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("yo you are in IW Portable Area, congrats");
        }
    }
}
```

-I added a reference in my main project to the portable area: IWPortableArea.dll

-Finally I modified the Global.asax.cs of my main application to:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Portal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats the aspx in "iw/{controller}.aspx/{action}" for?

Comment: The IIS on our webserver does support url without an ".aspx" Without the .aspx I get an 404 error. So In my post, when I say http://localhost:123/IW/Home it should be http://localhost:123/IW/Home.aspx

Comment: Did you change the compile action of the area view to Embedded Resource?

Answer (score 2):

Remember to create a folder with the name "Areas" in the hosting application. This solved my problem.